# Tensorflow 2.0: Shape inference with Reshape returns None dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm working with a CNN-LSTM model on Tensorflow 2.0 + Keras to perform sequence classification. My model is defined as following:

```py
    inp = Input(input_shape)
    rshp = Reshape((input_shape[0]*input_shape[1], 1), input_shape=input_shape)(inp)
    cnn1 = Conv1D(100, 9, activation='relu')(rshp)
    cnn2 = Conv1D(100, 9, activation='relu')(cnn1)
    mp1 = MaxPooling1D((3,))(cnn2)
    cnn3 = Conv1D(50, 3, activation='relu')(mp1)
    cnn4 = Conv1D(50, 3, activation='relu')(cnn3)
    gap1 = AveragePooling1D((3,))(cnn4)
    dropout1 = Dropout(rate=dropout[0])(gap1)
    flt1 = Flatten()(dropout1)
    rshp2 = Reshape((input_shape[0], -1), input_shape=flt1.shape)(flt1)
    bilstm1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(240,
                                 return_sequences=True,
                                 recurrent_dropout=dropout[1]),
                            merge_mode=merge)(rshp2)
    dense1 = TimeDistributed(Dense(30, activation='relu'))(rshp2)
    dropout2 = Dropout(rate=dropout[2])(dense1)
    prediction = TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))(dropout2)

    model = Model(inp, prediction, name="CNN-bLSTM_per_segment")
    print(model.summary(line_length=75))
```

Where `input_shape = (60, 60)`. This definition, however, raises the following error:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'`

At first, I thought it was because the `rshp2` layer could not reshape the `flt1` output to shape `(60, X)`. So I added a printing block before the `Bidirectional(LSTM))` layer:

```py
    print('reshape1: ', rshp.shape)
    print('cnn1: ', cnn1.shape)
    print('cnn2: ', cnn2.shape)
    print('mp1: ', mp1.shape)
    print('cnn3: ', cnn3.shape)
    print('cnn4: ', cnn4.shape)
    print('gap1: ', gap1.shape)
    print('flatten 1: ', flt1.shape)
    print('reshape 2: ', rshp2.shape)
```

And the shapes were:

```
reshape 1:  (None, 3600, 1)
cnn1:  (None, 3592, 100)
cnn2:  (None, 3584, 100)
mp1:  (None, 1194, 100)
cnn3:  (None, 1192, 50)
cnn4:  (None, 1190, 50)
gap1:  (None, 396, 50)
flatten 1:  (None, 19800)
reshape 2:  (None, 60, None)
```

Looking at the `flt1` layer, its output shape is `(19800,)`, which can be reshaped as `(60, 330)`, but for some reason the `(60, -1)` of the `rshp2` layer is not working as intended, evidenced by the print `reshape 2:  (None, 60, None)`. When I try to reshape as `(60, 330)` it works just fine. Does anyone knows why the `(-1)` is not working?

Answer (score 1):

`-1` is working.

From `Reshape` documentation, https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Reshape

the layer returns a tensor with shape `(batch_size,) + target_shape`

So, the batch size stays the same, the other dimensions are calculated based on your `target_shape`.

From the doc, look at the last example,

```
# also supports shape inference using `-1` as dimension
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1, 2, 2)))
model.output_shape
```

`(None, None, 2, 2)`

If you pass `-1` in your target shape, the Keras will store `None`, this is useful if you expect variable-length data in that axis, but if your data shape is always same, just put the dimension hard-coded that will place the dimension when you print the shape later.

N.B: Also no need to specify `input_shape=input_shape` for your intermediate layers in functional API. The model will infer that for you.